# XML deserialization generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, serialization, xml-deserialization

I have next XML file:

```
<Root>
    <Document>      
        <Id>d639a54f-baca-11e1-8067-001fd09b1dfd</Id>
        <Balance>-24145</Balance>
    </Document>
    <Document>      
        <Id>e3b3b4cd-bb8e-11e1-8067-001fd09b1dfd</Id>
        <Balance>0.28</Balance> 
    </Document>
</Root>
```

I deserialize it to this class:

```
[XmlRoot("Root", IsNullable = false)]
public class DocBalanceCollection
{
    [XmlElement("Document")]
    public List<DocBalanceItem> DocsBalanceItems = new List<DocBalanceItem>();
}
```

where `DocBalanceItem` is:

```
public class DocBalanceItem
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public Guid DocId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Balance")]
    public decimal? BalanceAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my deserialization method:

```
public DocBalanceCollection DeserializeDocBalances(string filePath)
{
    var docBalanceCollection = new DocBalanceCollection();

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(docBalanceCollection.GetType());
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        docBalanceCollection = (DocBalanceCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }

    return docBalanceCollection;
}
```

All works fine but I have many XML files. Besides writing `Item` classes I have to write `ItemCollection` classes for each of them. And also I have to implement `DeserializeItems` method for each.

**Can I deserialize my XML files without creating `ItemCollection` classes? And can I write single generic method to deserialize all of them?**

The only solution that comes to mind - make an interface for all these classes. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using `dynamic` ?

Comment: I am not sure it will work. Anyway I need to specify [XmlRoot("Root", IsNullable = false)] and [XmlElement("Document")] somewere. Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can deserialize a generic `List<T>` just fine with XmlSerializer. However, first you need to add the `XmlType` attribute to your `DocBalanceItem` so it knows how the list elements are named.

```
[XmlType("Document")]
public class DocBalanceItem
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public Guid DocId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Balance")]
    public decimal? BalanceAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify your `DeserializeDocBalances()` method to return a `List<T>` and pass the serializer an `XmlRootAttribute` instance to instruct it to look for `Root` as the root element:

```
public List<T> DeserializeList<T>(string filePath)
{
    var itemList = new List<T>();

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute("Root"));
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        itemList = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }

    return itemList;
}
```

Then you should be able to do

`var list = DeserializeList<DocBalanceItem>("somefile.xml");`

Since the method now returns a generic `List<T>`, you no longer need to create custom collections for every type.

P.S. - I tested this solution locally with the provided document, it does work.

Comment: Updated my answer so that `DeserializeDocBalances` is renamed to `DeserializeList` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it a bit later

Answer (score 1):

Any stringable object can be deserialized by following method.

```
public static T genericDeserializeSingleObjFromXML<T>(T value, string XmalfileStorageFullPath)
        {             
            T Tvalue = default(T);
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(XmalfileStorageFullPath);
                Tvalue = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
                textReader.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("serialization Error : " + ex.Message);                
            }
            return Tvalue;
        }
```

In order to use this method you should already serialize the object in xml file.
Calling method is :

```
XmlSerialization.genericDeserializeSingleObjFromXML(new ObjectName(), "full path of the XML file");
```